# One definition rule across DLL libraries from C++ standards point-of-view

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer

I have a badly designed DLL library header that use `TCHAR` in its header as a struct member*:

```
struct A {
  int nType;
  TCHAR szData[128];
};
```

And also there's a DLL function that passed `struct A**` as an argument to return a dynamic allocated array of type `struct A` and its length:

```
void func(int *pnCount, struct A **ppArray);
```

Since in the DLL library, we use Multi-Byte Character Set in the project setting, `TCHAR` is `char`.
But in the application, we set Unicode Character Set, and `TCHAR` is actually `wchar_t`.

Since for some reason, I can not modify the header file, how can I call this DLL function without violating the rules?

1. Does strict aliasing rule applied across library boundary? I think compiler can not do fancy optimizations on this DLL interface.
2. If I define the struct on my own (without including the header) in my application project as:

```
struct A {
  int nType;
  char szData[128];
};

void func(int *pnCount, struct A **ppArray);
```

It looks like I didn't violate any rule including strict aliasing rule, doesn't it?

3. Since I must include the header, can I use another struct name without violating strict aliasing rule or other rules?

```
struct A2 {
  int nType;
  char szData[128];
};
```

3a. It looks like I need to use some kind of casts to archive this, which of them should I use?

3b. Or can I forward declare the DLL function or dynamically load the DLL function with another signature?

```
void func(int *pnCount, struct A2 **ppData);
```

4. What about if the usage is not across library boundary, but only across source files (translation units)?

*The following is just simplified example of my real case.

---

Update:

After reading [walnut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11941443/walnut)'s answer I realized this may related to one-definition-rule of the standard rather than strict aliasing rule so I changed the title.

Also, to make it's more specific, I remove the C tag.

Comment: I don't understand why you would define A2 to be *the same structure.* That seems redundant. I thought you want to make szData a wchar_t?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I understood the question as OP not intending `wchar_t` for `szData`, but just having the issue that the `TCHAR` macro is defined differently and cannot be changed.

Comment: What has any of this got to do with strict aliasing?

Comment: C or C++? Make up your mind, they are apparently different in this case, as in almost every other case.

Comment: @walnut Oh. I see, the same header definition results in different structs in app vs. dll.  About the opposite of what one would like to achieve by using a typedef, usually. Errrr... that may cause more subtle problems under the hood. The solution is obviously to re-compile the dll with the project settings, or, lacking the source, to obtain a wchar_t compiled dll binary, or, if that is unavailable, to align the project settings with the dll's, or to marshal any in- and outgoing data.

Comment: @Lundin The OP would access something declared `A` (with, from the project's perspective, an array of `wchar_t`) as an `A2`, with a simple `char` array, by casting a pointer. (The twist being that the aliasing has already happened, not by name but by substance (violating the one definition rule), when the function returns, and would be *reverted* (not by name, but by substance) by the cast.)

Comment: The standard says nothing about DLLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ from a standards point-of-view (given the `language-lawyer` tag). In practice you can get away with much more:

> 1. Does strict aliasing rule applied across library boundary? I think compiler can not do fancy optimizations on this DLL interface.

Yes, it does. However, you are not actually asking anything about the strict aliasing rule, as far as I can tell. Your questions seem to rather be about the one-definition-rule.

> 2. If I define the struct on my own (without including the header) in my application project as:

Yes, that is completely fine, as long as the token sequence (after macro replacement) is exactly the same as in the header used to build the library.

> 3. Since I must include the header, can I use another struct name without violating strict aliasing rule or other rules?

No, you cannot. You would be declaring a different type and a different function and accessing `A2` through a pointer to `A` (or the other way around) would be undefined behavior.

Additionally, inclusion of the original header (without guarding it in some way so as to not include the mismatching definition) would already cause the program to violate the one-definition-rule and therefore have undefined behavior.

> 4. What about if the usage is not across library boundary, but only across source files (translation units)?

The same answers. The standard doesn't know a difference between the two. It only refers to translation units.

Comment: "as long as the token sequence (after macro replacement) is exactly the same" Is alias using `typedef` or `using` considered the same also?

Comment: Regarding 3), the two structs appear to be compatible types (100% identical members) and then you can convert between them just fine. That has nothing to do with strict aliasing, but struct compatibility rules.

Comment: @Lundin Not in C++.

Comment: @Willy The standard requires the token sequence to be identical, so if aliases are used, they must be named the same: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6.1. Of course in practice that wouldn't really matter. Also note the additional requirements in the linked standard passage on when names may refer to  different entities. These requirements are in addition to the matching token sequence requirement.

Comment: Oh ffs, not this again... OP tag your question with _one_ language.

Comment: @Lundin In C++ the only special rule about layout-compatible structs is that a union of them may inspect the inactive one's members, which would otherwise be UB. But that doesn't help OP because it would require defining that union, which would require defining `A` appropriately (which they seem to not be able to).

Comment: Is my application already ill-formed by the C++ standards when I include the header from my application? Or when I use the struct to define a variable?

Comment: @Willy Merely including the mismatching definition causes the program to have undefined behavior according to the standard. But again, that would probably look different in practice.

Comment: @Lundin two structs with different tags are incompatible types even if they have the same members  (in both languages)

Comment: @walnut Got it. So in practice, if I still need to include the header, I can define another struct (like the `A2`) or function signature with same binary structure to solve this problem, right?

Comment: @Willy In practice you can probably get away with defining `A2` and accessing the `A` object through a `A2` pointer (by `reinterpret_cast`ing) in this particular case, but it is not a very stable solution, see also the comment by Peter under your question.

Comment: @Willy This is also assuming that the problematic `A` definition included from the header isn't actually used in any function definitions or the like, because otherwise the odr-violations can quickly cascade to something where it *is* practically relevant. And if there is any kind of link-time-optiimization, then you will get into trouble as well.